# Add an ImageView at the bottom of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I have a TableViewController class :-

```
class SideMenuViewController: UITableViewController {

     let tableViewFooter = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.size.height + 80, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 80))

     tableViewFooter.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "nav_drawer_footer.jpg")!)
     tableView.tableFooterView  = tableViewFooter

}
```

But using this code ..the view is under the last cell of tableView....i don't want this.

What I need is an ImageView / UIView at the Bottom of the table view Controller

Comment: add the UIImageView or UIView underneath the table view. it doesn't have to be inside it. just constrain the bottom of the tableview to the top of the other view

Answer (score 2):

```
    let theHeight = view.frame.size.height //grabs the height of your view
    let footer = UIView()
    footer.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "nav_drawer_footer.jpg")!)
    footer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: theHeight - 150 , width: self.view.frame.width, height: 80)
    self.view.addSubview(footer)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView()
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    //Write UIImageView required code
    footer.addSubView(imgView)

    return footerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

       return HEIGHT_YOU_WANT
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do this with UIViewController with separate UITableView and UIImageView instead of using UITableViewController.When using UITableViewController self.view is actually self.tableView, i.e. your image will be a subview of the UITableView and it will overlap the bottom rows. It is also better to use layout constraints than frame rects. As constraints code is somewhat a pain to write you can use [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) as I did here:

```
import SnapKit

class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    let tableViewFooter = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableViewFooter.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "nav_drawer_footer.jpg")!)

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        view.addSubview(tableViewFooter)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        tableViewFooter.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.width.equalTo(view.snp.width)
            make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left)
            make.bottom.equalTo(view.snp.bottom)
            make.height.equalTo(80)
        }

        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(view.snp.top)
            make.bottom.equalTo(tableViewFooter.snp.top)
            make.width.equalTo(view.snp.width)
            make.centerX.equalTo(view.snp.centerX)
        }

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return cell
    }

}
```

Edit: I am using SnapKit just so I don't write all this constraints code.The point is in the logic.